# Trying to understand LSTM parameter hidden_size in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

Going of LSTM documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html#torch.nn.LSTM

I will be referring to this picture for the rest of my post:

[LSTM block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULpUN.png)

I think I understand what input_size is:

`input_size` - the number of input features per time-step:
So if the input is a vector, maybe a word embedding. (Represented as X_t in the baove piture)

What is is `hidden_size`?
According to this stack overflow post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50848068/14382150

`hidden_size` is referred to as number of nodes in 1 LSTM cell. BUt he does not explain very well what he means by node.

Can someone please give a clear explanation of what `hidden_size` is referring to? Is it just the number of time steps the LSTM block unrolled?

Also what size should it be? Is it like a hyperparameter, similar to defining number of neurons in a fully connected neural network.

I have looked at multiple posts and videos but I cant seem to understand this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hidden size is just the number of lstm block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hidden_size` is a hyper-parameter and it refers to the dimensionality of the vector **h**_t. It has nothing to do with the number of LSTM blocks, which is another hyper-parameter (`num_layers`). It is also explained by the user in the other post you linked.

Since it is a hyper-parameter, what its value should be needs to be found empirically for the particular task at hand.

If you pick your `hidden_size` equal to **H** and the input size is **X**, notice that parameter matrices W_ii, W_if, W_ig, W_io will be **H**x**X** matrices, whereas W_hi, W_hf, W_hg and W_ho will be matrices of size **H**x**H**. In practice, these 8 matrices (4 **H**x**X** matrices and 4 **H**x**H** matrices) are implemented as a two **4H**x**X** and **4H**x**H** matrices in pytorch.

[image]

The **4H** parameters you see here are the bias terms.